# Rails form select to return all params in an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I have an list in my controller that looks like:

```
@relatives = [
    {
        id: '1',
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        related: 'Father'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        firstName: 'Sarah',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        related: 'Mother'
    }
]
```

I would like to put this list in a form select in my view. So it would be a drop-down of relatives, but it would only display the firstName field in the select. When the user selects an object and submits the form, the *entire* relative object would get passed to the controller in the params.

I was looking at the rails collection_select API, but couldn't figure out how to select an entire object in the form.

Comment: where is this data generated from? isn't it coming from a database or something ?

Comment: Yeah my data is coming from a database, via a REST service.

Comment: So I can use this `f.select :relative, options_from_collection_for_select(@relatives, 'id', 'firstName')`, but that will only set the :relative parameter to the id field. I need the :relative parameter to have a set of sub-parameters that include all fields. Does that make sense?

Comment: @32clemons ahh i thought you were using ActiveRecord. Try using this: `f.select :relative, @relatives.each {|r| [ r[:firstName], r ]}`

Comment: I just tried that, but when it submits the form, the actual :relative parameter is just a string containing "#<Relative:0x0...>". So it looks like it's trying to return the full object, but it's coming across as a string. Would I need to define my parameters differently I wonder?

Comment: @32clemons haven't really worked with activeresource so not the best person to suggest but if it's coming across as a string then you need to find a way to serialize that field, like we do in activerecord

Comment: Thanks Mandeep, I'll keep looking.

Comment: how often do these relatives change, you could cache them on your server then reuse them when the id is submitted in the form

Comment: They won't change very often. I guess I could just read the data in memory and manually build out the new parameters based on the id. I was hoping for something a little more pretty though :) Can't seem to find a way to serialize an ActiveResource object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I decided the best way to accomplish this is to just create a hash in my controller with the key being the display text and the value being a JSON representation of my object.

Controller:

```
@relatives = {
    "John" => "{id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', related: 'Father'}",
    "Sarah" => "{id: 2, firstName: 'Sarah', lastName: 'Smith', related: 'Mother'}"
}
```

Then in my view, I'll use options_for_select:

```
f.select :relative, options_for_select(@relatives)
```

When the user select a value and submits the form, the JSON string will be returned in the parameters as the value. From the controller, I'll just convert the JSON back to a model. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Rails 7**

It probably also works for other versions as i just worked with Rails 7.

```
<%= form.collection_radio_buttons :address, @addresses, :to_json, :label %>
```

As the :symbol you provide for `id` and `value` actually calls anything the object provides, it is possible to provide a list of objects and use the `to_json` method directly.

This will add all the attributes of the address object as a json string to params. As @32clemons already mentioned you have to convert it back in the controller.

PS: my address object:

```
{
id: null --> it's a new object and not provided jet,
label: string --> a full description of the address,
city: string,
....
}
```

> :label can be also defined as a function in the model as a combination of the other attributes of the address object, but in my case it is a return value of the API (HERE Maps) i'm using to check the address.